# How to insert records of a table into another table having same structure but different database?

Tags: mysql

I have three databases in same server which having same kind of tables as below.

**City**

```
id -> primary_key
name
```

**Contacts**

```
id -> primary_key
city_id -> foreign_key
name
number
```

First and second databases having some cities and contacts related to those cities. Now I want to insert all the data from both the databases into third database. So I tried it with import/export database but primary key values are being conflicted.

For city table I can insert data manually as 2 3 cities are there in both the databases but it's not convenient for contacts as contacts are approx 5000. So how can I do it with some easy way?

Comment: Please do not use tags that do not apply to your question.

Comment: Also, at [so] you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use simple INSERT statement (database_name.[schema_name].table)

```
INSERT [NewDB].[your_schema].[City](Id,Name) 
SELECT id, Name
FROM [OldDB].[your_schema].[City]
where _your where clause_
```

you can see here: 
[Insert data from db to another db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15653732/insert-data-from-db-to-another-db)

and here:[How to insert table values from one database to another database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502269/how-to-insert-table-values-from-one-database-to-another-database)

Comment: Thank You! it's working but I had to add `SET foreign_key_checks = 0` before and `SET foreign_key_checks = 1` after my insert query

Comment: That is always 

in such copy (repeated copz to a data base): you must deactivate the foreign key checking and when the copy is finished you activate it again

normally: such a copy take place one time for all the needed tables.